# Why setOnCheckedChangeListener not working in a popup that uses LayoutInflater?

Tags: android, popup, radio-group

I have a RadioGroup in a popup. When i put setoncheckedchangelistener it causes an error. here's my code. The error says that it is not applicable to the arguments (new Compound Button.OnCheckedChangeListener.. i don't understand can somebody pls help me?

```
   private void showPopupSeat(final Activity context) 
   {       
       int popupWidth = 500;
       int popupHeight = 650;


   // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
   LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popupseat);


   LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.seat_dimension, viewGroup);


  RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) layout.findViewById(R.id.rg1);
  final RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.option1);
  final RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.option2);
  final RadioButton rb3 = (RadioButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.option3);

      rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
      {
          public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

          }
  });


   final PopupWindow popupseat = new PopupWindow(context);
   popupseat.setContentView(layout);
   popupseat.setWidth(popupWidth);
   popupseat.setHeight(popupHeight);
   popupseat.setFocusable(true);


   // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the right, and a bit down, relative to button's position.
   int OFFSET_X = 30;
   int OFFSET_Y = 260;

     // Clear the default translucent background
   popupseat.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

   // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
   popupseat.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
  }
```

i dont know what is wrong.. pls help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead importing

`import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;`

Import

`import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;`

same issue discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/PemtaXI9tpg).