# can't set onCheckedChangeListener to RadioGroup

Tags: android, radio-button, listener, radio-group

I've created my RadioGroup as following:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
```

Now I wanted to call the onCheckedChangeListener like this:

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

    }

});
```

First, eclipse suggests me to write it like this, but when having typed it all out, Eclipse underlines my code like this:

[image]

the **.setOnCheckedChangeListener** is red and tells me follwing:

```
The method setOnCheckedChangeListener(RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener) 
in the type RadioGroup is not applicable for the arguments 
(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){})
```

Why won't my Listener work properly although eclipse first tells me to do it like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why setOnCheckedChangeListener not working in a popup that uses LayoutInflater?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973909/why-setoncheckedchangelistener-not-working-in-a-popup-that-uses-layoutinflater)

Comment: Did you add the required imports ???

Comment: use RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener; instead of CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener; =)

Answer (score 3):

add the import:

```
 import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
```

instead of:

```
 import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
```

and your code will work like a charm :) :

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);    
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {   
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            }
        });
```

the problem is that you are using:

```
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
```

Comment: What if I have another component widget `CheckBox` of which needs `import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;`,that conflicts each other.

Comment: have you tried with "fully qualified class name" for example: .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

Answer (score 0):

check your "import" section in file top. 
use

```
"import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;"
```

instead of

```
"import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use/import `RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener` instead of `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener`:

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedId) {
        // TODO
    }
});
```